# Reading and manipulating a file in python

Tags: python, file

```
def ints(filename):
    a = []
    f = open(filename, "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for line in lines:
        numbers = line.split()
        for number in numbers:            
            a.append(int(number))
    return a
```

This is my function so far, I want to be able to read a file containing integers and characters like "x" and "b" etc and return a list of only the integers. At the moment the function can only deal with a file containing integers.

How can I modify this to exclude characters or letters?

Comment: Can you give an example of the file contents you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my edit of your code, which performs as you expect it to.

```
  def ints(filename):
        """A function that takes the filename of a file as an input arguement, computs and returns a list of
        integers of all the numbers in the file."""
        a = []
        f = open(filename, "r")
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        for line in lines:
            for character in line:
                try:
                    a.append(int(character))
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        return a
```

Comment: Weird that this got accepted, only working for numbers surrounded  by spaces: `abc123cba` will ignore `123`

Comment: @Mahi Oh thanx for the notice, however, this is something so easy to fix.

Comment: Still could be improved, for `"1 19 532 2"` it returns `[1, 1, 9, 5, 3, 2, 2]` instead of `[1, 19, 532, 2]` as does Chris Harris' answer.

Comment: @Mahi I'm sorry, but the question leave's me under the impression that the op wants single digit numbers. If he requests otherwise, then I shall change it.

Answer (score 2):

`regex` can be helpful here:

A simple example:

```
In [22]: import re

In [23]: strs="121 some 34useless text 56"

In [24]: map(int,re.findall("\d+",strs))
Out[24]: [121, 34, 56]

# or this If you want the individual digits:

In [40]: map(int,re.findall("\d",strs))
Out[40]: [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

For your code this should work:

```
for line in lines:
    numbers = map(int,re.findall("\d+",line))
    a.extend(numbers)
```

Comment: +1 nice idea. Although I firmly believe that regex are hard at this point for the op, since it's obvious he has recently got started with python.

Comment: you mean `line` instead of `strs` on the second example? :)

Answer (score 1):

I just simply tested if characters were numbers:

```
sample_string = "Test4. 2325This string3"
a_list = []
for x in sample_string:
    if x.isdigit():
        a_list.append(x)
```

Comment: 1) It returns `['4', '2', '3', '2', '5', '3']` instead of `[4, 2325, 3]`. 2) By `a.append(x)` I guess you actually meant `a_list.append(x)`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes. I was sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

```
for number in numbers:
    try:
        a.append(int(number))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try/catch might help:

```
for thing in line.split():
    i_thing = None
    try:
        i_thing = int(thing)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    s_thing = None
    try:
        s_thing = str(thing)
    except:
        raise Exception("OH NOES!")
```

It's pretty ugly, but I haven't found a nicer way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using more modern Python idioms:

```
def ints(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            for number in line.split():
                try:
                    yield int(number)
                except ValueError:
                    pass


a = list(ints("testdata.txt"))
print(a)
```

Basically, try to convert to int, which will raise ValueError if the string is not a decimal number. Catch it and ignore it and carry on.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [string.translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) etc. to just replaces all non digits with spaces then leverage the power of split() and map().

Granted it's a little obscure and my default response would be to just use the [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module as on the whole there's so much more you can do with Regular Expressions, that they're worth the effort in learning.

```
In [119]: import string
In [120]: allchars = string.maketrans('', '')
In [121]: delchars = allchars.translate(allchars, "0123456789")
In [122]: emptychars = string.maketrans(delchars, ' ' * len(delchars))
In [123]: "Welcome home 1234 56 ol".translate(emptychars)
Out[123]: '             1234 56   '
In [124]: "Welcome home 1234 56 ol".translate(emptychars).split()
Out[124]: ['1234', '56']
In [125]: map(int, "Welcome home 1234 56 ol".translate(emptychars).split())
Out[125]: [1234, 56]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested sudo-code, but should be valid.  Also the best advice I can give is watch David Beazley's Generator Tricks for Systems programmers and Mastering Python 3 I/O talks. They were a great help in learning python.

This is just a simple generator to fetch each line of a file and close the file afterwards.

```
def getLine(fileName):
    file = open(fileName, "r")

    for line in file.readLines():
        yield line

    file.close()


def getNumbers(line):
// I'm lazy and stole this one from Keith
    for number in line.split():
        try:
            yield int(number)
        except ValueError:
            pass

def generatorChain(fileName):
    // I'm a little iffy on the syntax here, but shouldn't be to hard with a bit of googling
    fileGen = getLine(fileName);
    yield getNumber( fileGen.next() ).next()

def listCompressionMagic():
    return [x for x in generatorChain("foo.txt") ]
```